# Right way to read modules in multi-module project

Tags: maven-plugin

Wondering what would be the best approach to read and resolve all modules in multi-module project?

For example i want to build only a single module but at the same time i want to know about all modules around (without building). I've found `project.getArtifacts` but it includes also libraries and other stuff.

Was thinking more of the approach to `project.getParent().getModules().foreach(it -> MavenXpp3Reader.read(basedir.resolve(it)))....` but in this case inherited properties in modules will be lost. Like `<version>${revision}</version>`.
Wondering if there may be a better way to do that?